# Summing values based on days and cost - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tutorial on summing sub values to get a total value based on cost and days using JavaScript just like below.

```
 Facebook Marketing ads
    days : 2  
    Cost : $5      
    Total : $10

 Twitter Marketing ads
    days : 10
    Cost : $5 
    Total : $50

Instagram Marketing ads  
        days : 10
        Cost : $10 
        Total : $100

     Total Cost : $50 + $10 + $100= $160
```

I am able to get all sub prices but my issue is summing the sub values to get the grand total.

This is what happens in my console

When i add a third item, it produces the `total cost and also the sub value of the third item selected and takes it as the total cost`

when i select **Facebook Marketing ads**
`the total cost : 10` //which is accurate

when i add  **Twitter Marketing ads**
`the total cost : 60` //which is accurate

when i add  **Instagram Marketing ads**
  `the total cost : 160`// accurate

`the total cost : 100` // but i produces this line as the final value

**JS**

```
function select(ad) {
  $('.panel').append(
    '<div class="marketing">' +
    '<p class="name">Ad Selected: ' + ad.name + '</p>' +
    '<p class="cost"   data-price="' + ad.value + '"> Cost  :  '+ ad.value+ '</p>' +
    '<input type="text" class="days" name="days" /'> +
    '<p class="total">Total   $:</p>' +
    '</div>'
  )

  $('.panel').on('keyup', '.days', function() {
    var marketing = $(this).closest('div');
    var days = Number($(this).val());
    var cost = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.cost').data('cost'));
    marketing.find(".total").text(days * cost);
    sum += days * cost;

     console.log('the total cost  '+sum);
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <input onclick="return select(this)" type="checkbox" id="{{ad->id}}" name="Facebook" value="{{ad->value}}" />
</div>
<p class="total_ads" style="text-align: center">Total Cost $:</p>
<div class="panel" id="panel"></div>
```

I'm a beginner with JavaScript and jQuery. I am not able to get it working in a snippet

Comment: You pass `this` to the function ad. `this` is the `input` itself. You want to pass the `ad` and you don't do this.

Comment: @MoshFeu you mean i should replace `ad` with `this` in the function `select`?

Comment: If `ad` is a global variable you can do this. When this param come from?

Comment: @MoshFeu, if i replace `ad` with `this` in function `select`, the function doesn't work any longer

Comment: Sure, because `ad` is not defined.That's what I asked. Where `ad` param come from?

Comment: @MoshFeu  ad is  from to the `(this)` in the input checkbox. so whatever is selected in `this` is for `ad`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157986/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-amateur).